# Need to fetch multi enum value for every work item

Tags: enums, velocity, vtl

In my report i need to print yes or no values by fetching values from multi select enum custom field for every work item ,if work item's custom field has value then need to print as yes into the column ,else print as No, similarly need to check for each for each work item .

I am using the below code snippet , but its not working , can anyone please help me to resolve this As soon as possible  .

```
#foreach($ref in $refList)

  #set($refWi = $transaction.workItems().getBy().oldApiObject($ref))
  #set($arr=[$refWi.fields().get("Values")])

  #foreach($item in $arr)   
    #if($item == "Tablets")
      #set($isTablet = "YES")
    #else
      #set($isTablet = "NO")
    #end
  #end
#end

Printing the YES/No value .
```

Comment: To debug, you can just print `$item` to understand what's inside. And you're telling us that it doesn't work, but not what happens exactly.

Comment: Thank you for ur reply @ClaudeBrisson , I have tried printing $item but nothing was printing .and  by using the above code , I get the  output as False in every row i.e., it is taking defaullt value and printing in every row .Now , main concern here is , I couldn't able to get the enum value to the array or any referenced value to store . So, could u pls help me to fetch the enum vaue of work item

Comment: So the problem is before. You can try to print every intermediary step and variable to understand what happens. Since we don't know the input parameters, we cannot help you more.

Answer (score 0):

By doing below it seems to me that you put an array into another one, therefore $arr is a matrix of a single $item that will be what $arr should have been.

> #set($arr=[$refWi.fields().get("Values")])

Considering this is an old topic and probably you fixed the issue already, it would be nice to know for others that may come to this topic, which was the solution.